# Updating a globalForwardingRules in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to update the target of a global forwarding rule via the rest api, but I can't get it to work.
This command works in the console.

```
gcloud compute forwarding-rules set-target fw-rule --global --target-http-proxy lb-target-proxy
```

But if I use the node.js lib or the API explorer provided by the documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/globalForwardingRules/setTarget

I get a "The URL is malformed." error:
[image]

```
"message": "Invalid value for field 'target.target': 'lb-target-proxy'. The URL is malformed."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/globalForwardingRules#ForwardingRule.FIELDS.target):

> **Target**: The URL of the target resource to receive the matched traffic.

So the target has to be the full URL of the resource, not just the ID.

It might be easier to try the [`list` methof of the same API](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/globalForwardingRules/list). There you'll see the format of the target:

`"https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/<PROJECT_ID>/global/targetHttpProxies/<TARGET_ID>"`